# New Question: Serious problem by creating a figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, floats, pstricks, tikz-styles

I have now trying to make this model:

[image]

But I do not know how to add the nodes in top; "1 text", "2 text", "3 text" and "4 text". Furthermore, I do not know how to make a fourth box, as shown: "9 text text".

My preamble look like this:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    mytext/.style={
      draw,
      text width=#1,
      align=center,
      minimum height=1.5cm
      },
    ar/.style={
      ->,
      >=latex
      }  
    ]
    \node[mytext=3cm,minimum height=8cm] (left)
      {2 text text text};
    \node[mytext=4cm,anchor=north west] 
      at ([xshift=1.5cm]left.north east) (middle1)
      {4 text text text};
    \node[mytext=4cm,anchor=west] 
      at ([xshift=1.5cm]left.east) (middle2)
      {5 text text text};
    \node[mytext=4cm,anchor=south west] 
      at ([xshift=1.5cm]left.south east) (middle3)
      {6 text text text};
    \node[mytext=3cm,minimum height=8cm,anchor=north west] 
      at ([xshift=1.5cm]middle1.north east) (right)
      {8 text text text};
    \coordinate (aux) at ([yshift=3cm]middle1);
    \node[mytext=4cm,dashed,minimum height=0.8cm,anchor=north] 
      at (aux) (middle0)
      {3 text text};  
    \node[mytext=3cm,dashed,anchor=north] 
      at (left.center|-aux) (left0)
      {1 text text};  
    \node[mytext=3cm,dashed,anchor=north] 
      at (right.center|-aux) (right0)
      {7 text text};
    \draw
      ([shift={(-10pt,10pt)}]left0.north west)
        rectangle
      ([shift={(10pt,-10pt)}]right.south east);

    \foreach \Valor in {1,2,3}
    {
    \draw[ar]
      (left.east|-middle\Valor.west) -- (middle\Valor.west);    
    \draw[ar]
      (middle\Valor.east) -- (right.west|-middle\Valor.west);    
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}

EDIT:

@Ignasi have been very helpful to create the figure above - by using this:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
mytext/.style={
  draw,
  text width=#1,
  align=center,
  minimum height=1.5cm
  },
ar/.style={
  ->,
  >=latex
  }  
]
\node[mytext=3cm,minimum height=8cm] (left)
  {1 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,right=1.5cm of left] (middle2)
  {2 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,anchor=north west] at (left.north-|middle2.west) 
  (middle1)
  {3 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,anchor=south west] at (left.south-|middle2.west) 
  (middle3)
  {4 text text text};
\node[mytext=3cm,minimum height=8cm,right=1.5cm of middle2] (right)
  {8 text text text};
\node[mytext=3cm,minimum height=8cm,right=1.5cm of right] (right-right)
  {9 text text text};

\node[mytext=3cm, dashed, above=1cm of left] (d-left) {1 text text};
\node[mytext=4cm, dashed, above=1cm of middle1] (d-middle) {2 text text};
\node[mytext=3cm, dashed, above=1cm of right] (d-right) {3 text text};
\node[mytext=3cm, dashed, above=1cm of right-right] (d-right-right) {4 text text};

\foreach \i/\j in {1/d-left, 2/d-middle, 3/d-right, 4/d-right-right}
    \draw ([yshift=1cm]\j.north west)--node [above] {\i\ text} ([yshift=1cm]\j.north east);

\foreach \i in {middle1, middle2, middle3}{
    \draw[ar] (left.east|-\i)--(\i);
    \draw[ar] (\i)--(right.west|-\i);
    }

\draw[ar] (right) -- (right-right);

\node[fit={(left) (right-right) ([yshift=2cm]d-left.north west)}, draw, inner sep=8,,] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My question is: Is there an easy way of creating the table below by changing the code above?

EDIT

@Ignasi have been so great to create the figure above by using the following code sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
mytext/.style={
  draw,
  text width=#1,
  align=center,
  minimum height=1.5cm
  },
ar/.style={
  ->,
  >=latex
  }  
]
\node[mytext=3cm,minimum height=8cm] (left)
  {1 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,right=1.5cm of left] (middle2)
  {2 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,anchor=north west] at (left.north-|middle2.west) 
  (middle1)
  {3 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,anchor=south west] at (left.south-|middle2.west) 
  (middle3)
  {4 text text text};
\node[mytext=3cm,minimum height=8cm,right=1.5cm of middle2] (right)
  {8 text text text};
\node[mytext=3cm,minimum height=8cm,right=1.5cm of right] (right-right)
  {9 text text text};

\node[mytext=3cm, dashed, above=1cm of left] (d-left) {1 text text};
\node[mytext=4cm, dashed, above=1cm of middle1] (d-middle) {2 text text};
\node[mytext=3cm, dashed, above=1cm of right] (d-right) {3 text text};
\node[mytext=3cm, dashed, above=1cm of right-right] (d-right-right) {4 text text};

\foreach \i/\j in {1/d-left, 2/d-middle, 3/d-right, 4/d-right-right}
    \draw ([yshift=1cm]\j.north west)--node [above] {\i\ text} ([yshift=1cm]\j.north east);

\foreach \i in {middle1, middle2, middle3}{
    \draw[ar] (left.east|-\i)--(\i);
    \draw[ar] (\i)--(right.west|-\i);
    }

\draw[ar] (right) -- (right-right);

\node[fit={(left) (right-right) ([yshift=2cm]d-left.north west)}, draw, inner sep=8,,] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like to know if it is possible to create the figure below by changing a bit in the sample code? I would appreciate any kind of help!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to use `positioning` library which can help you to place nodes beside/above/below others.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
mytext/.style={
  draw,
  text width=#1,
  align=center,
  minimum height=1.5cm
  },
ar/.style={
  ->,
  >=latex
  }  
]
\node[mytext=3cm,minimum height=8cm] (left)
  {1 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,right=1.5cm of left] (middle2)
  {2 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,anchor=north west] at (left.north-|middle2.west) 
  (middle1)
  {3 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,anchor=south west] at (left.south-|middle2.west) 
  (middle3)
  {4 text text text};
\node[mytext=3cm,minimum height=8cm,right=1.5cm of middle2] (right)
  {8 text text text};
\node[mytext=3cm,minimum height=8cm,right=1.5cm of right] (right-right)
  {9 text text text};

\node[mytext=3cm, dashed, above=1cm of left] (d-left) {1 text text};
\node[mytext=4cm, dashed, above=1cm of middle1] (d-middle) {2 text text};
\node[mytext=3cm, dashed, above=1cm of right] (d-right) {3 text text};
\node[mytext=3cm, dashed, above=1cm of right-right] (d-right-right) {4 text text};

\foreach \i/\j in {1/d-left, 2/d-middle, 3/d-right, 4/d-right-right}
    \draw ([yshift=1cm]\j.north west)--node [above] {\i\ text} ([yshift=1cm]\j.north east);

\foreach \i in {middle1, middle2, middle3}{
    \draw[ar] (left.east|-\i)--(\i);
    \draw[ar] (\i)--(right.west|-\i);
    }

\draw[ar] (right) -- (right-right);

\node[fit={(left) (right-right) ([yshift=2cm]d-left.north west)}, draw, inner sep=8,,] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Ignasi! I will look at positionering. Is there a way how to make the arrows from "1 text text text" goes from the middle to the three small boxes?

Comment: Hmm. I have now tried different things, but I can't figure out how to make the three arrows starting point in the middle of "1 text text text"

Comment: @A.F. Just change `\draw[ar] (left.east|-\i)--(\i);` by `\draw[ar] (left.east)--(\i.west);`

Comment: Dear Ignasi. Thank you so much. I have one last question: Is there an easy way of creating the new figure, that I have uploaded in this post - by using your code? I would appreciate the help very much!

Comment: @A.F. Did you try to understand the code? If you do it, I'm sure you'll know how to delete the fourth column. And for equally distributed blocks on second column, I'd suggest using `calc` library and its `x!z!y` construction. If you cannot do it, make a new question showing some effort and me or someone else will help you.

Comment: I have made a new question. As you can see, I only need to create a fourth box in the middle. I have now spend hours without luck.